# Load/Export RandomNumber

Tags: c++, ssl, crypto++, diffie-hellman

In the frame of an home-made [`ECDHE`](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Diffie-Hellman) application, both the client and the server have to send a randomly generated numbers (rng), in order to build later the `MasterSecret` during the handshake (TLS-like)...

With [crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/), it's easy to create these numbers, thanks to :

```
AutoSeededRandomPool rng;
```

My problem is 1) **to export them** to a string or equivalent, and 2) **to load them** from a string.

I must put these numbers within a frame, and nor the [Class definition](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_auto_seeded_random_pool.html), nor the [examples](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RandomNumberGenerator) precise that.

On the web I haven't been able to find Save/Load examples (like the ones for `RSA::PublicKeys`).

Apparently I'm the first to want this, as their [examples](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RandomNumberGenerator) generate the client and the server *in the same program*, and thus don't need to transmit the numbers.

And, as part of this handshake, I also try to do the same with curvesID...

Comment: Use `GenerateBlock (byte *output, size_t size)` to generate your random number then transfer it, encrypt it, print it on an orange sheet of paper, or do whatever you like with it. I think I don't understand your problem...

Comment: I thought that `prng` actually was the created random number. In fact, It's just a **generator**. And the `GenerateBlock` is a command to make it generate the Pseudo-Random Number. My bad.

Comment: @Beyeler should I delete my question ?

Comment: I don't actually know what SO says when a question turns out to be just a misunderstanding ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was a misunderstanding from my part, so I'll explain it, in case of anyone having the same interrogations. It's largely inspired from the [crypto++ wiki](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RandomNumberGenerator)...

There are 2 distinct objects :

```
AutoSeededRandomPool prng;

prng.GenerateBlock( scratch, scratch.size() );
```

`AutoSeededRandomPool prng;` is the generator of random numbers (that will be auto-seeded)

`prng.GenerateBlock` is the command that will extract bits from this random number to build the `std::string scratch` of the desired length.

And as the scratch is a string, we can do what we want with it, to use it anywhere... So please refer to the **string** import/export.